# How can I wait for asynchronous operations to complete when an Electron app is closed?

Tags: javascript, electron, asynchronous-javascript

I have an Electron JS desktop application that is supposed to do some closing operations when it's closed or quit. However, the app is closing before my asynchronous operations are ended.

How can I make the app wait for the asynchronous options to complete and close only when they are done?

Answer (score 1):

In my app, I do:

```
app.on("window-all-closed", async () => {
    await asyncThing();
    app.quit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Facing this issue and here is the code to handle async call before application quit (at least works for me):

Subscribe to `before-quit` event:

```
let flaqQuit = false;

app.on('before-quit', async function(event) {
    console.log('before-quit event triggered')

    if (!flagQuit) {
        // call this line to stop default behaviour occur 
        // (which is terminating the application)
        event.preventDefault();

        await callAsynchronousLogicHere();

        // Programmatically quit the application as previously 
        // we stop the quit behaviour
        app.quit();

        // Mark the variable to true, then later when 
        // quit it no longer entering this block of code
        flagQuit = true;
    }
});
```

As you can see, i use `flagQuit` variable to decide whether the code should enter if block for the 2nd call of `app.quit()`.

`before-quit` event will trigger when you press `CMD + Q` or call `app.quit()`, so this event will trigger twice and the `flagQuit` variable will handle this lifecycle for us.

Make sure to use `flaqQuit` otherwise this code will lead to infinite loop!

Answer (score -1):

You can use before-quit event in main process(main.js):

```
function task1() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // do something
    resolve("task1");
  });
}

function task2() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // do something
    resolve("task2");
  });
}

app.on('before-quit', function () {
  task1().then((_resp1) => {
    task2().then((_resp2) => {
      app.quit();
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: pretty sure you need to `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the actual quitting that will follow the `before-quit` event

Comment: I think there is no need for `e.preventDefault()` as app.quit will not trigger before the asynchronous `task1` and `task2` functions are completed in the `before-quit` event.

Comment: hm, it's not documented that it handles asynchrony. And besides, even if it does, I think you'd have to return the promise from within before-quit

Comment: `app.quit()` [triggers the `before-quit` event](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appquit), thus this code leads to an infinite loop.. The other method, `app.exit()` skips that event, but also skips `will-quit`, which might not be what you want depending on your requirements.